# RecyclerView scrollbar laggy

Tags: android, scrollbar, android-recyclerview

When I used the new recycler view, I noticed the scrollbar is not as fluid as in regular ScrollView/ListView. It looks like it doesn't recognize when you scroll within the adapter item, but it only changes when new item appears / old item disappears, so the progressbar jumps instead of move smoothly. [This is a video](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6LcqZn_AG41ZU93bmt4SmFrUTg/edit?usp=sharing) demonstrating this issue.
Is there a way to make it smooth?

My layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/listRecycler"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Fragment:

```
    mListRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    mListRecycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Adapter:

```
public class NewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<News> items;
private int itemLayout;

public NewsAdapter(List<News> items, int itemLayout) {
    this.items = items;
    this.itemLayout = itemLayout;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(itemLayout, parent, false);
    v.setOnClickListener(this);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    News item = items.get(position);
    holder.text.setText(item.getTitle());
    holder.itemView.setTag(item);
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    @InjectView(R.id.title)
    TextView text;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.inject(this, itemView);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Strangely the same lag happens with the other example you showed too, it just has more items, notice how the scrollbar handle wobbles a little when a view goes out of the screen.

Comment: can you update the thread with the latest version of RV + setting smooth scrollbars to true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is problem in L preview release. LinearLayoutManager did not have [smooth scrollbars support](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setSmoothScrollbarEnabled(boolean)).
Will be fixed when RecyclerView is released.

Comment: It still happens with 21.0.0

Comment: how is that, such a buggy code was released. It's not usable at all

Answer (score 0):

The RecyclerView also uses the height(if orientation vertical or width if horizontal) to compute the height(or width) of scrollbar. If your List item have same height(or width) then consider using setHasFixedSize().

```
mRecyclerList.setHasFixedSize(true);
```